# What does the following function mean?

Tags: neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

The following is the mathematical definition of a Artificial Neuron,

$$\textbf{Activation function } f: \qquad y = f(w^t x) = f\left( \sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i \right)$$

Given that $W$ is a vector, what does the symbol $t$ represent?

What operation does it represent on a vector $w$?

Comment: $w^t x$ is the weighted average of $x.$  Were $w$ represents the weights.  At least that is what it would be if all of the elements in $w$ are greater than $0$ and sum to $1.$

Comment: You used a lower-case $w$ and a capital $W$. If they both mean the same thing, you should use one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $t$ stands for transpose. The result of the matrix multiplication between $w^t$ and $x$ is then simply the scalar/dot product between $w$ and $x$, which in turn is just $\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i$:

$$w^tx = \begin{pmatrix}
w_1\\
w_2\\
\vdots\\
w_n\end{pmatrix}^t\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
w_1 \; w_2 \; \ldots \;w_n
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n\end{pmatrix} = w \cdot n = \sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i$$

Comment: Zillions of books say how matrix multiplication is defined, but nearly all of them omit to explain why it's defined that way, although that's easy to do. I wonder if some of that wouldn't help avert confusions about things like this.